# Ros Offline Installation

Tags: ros, installation, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am now working on Debian which I do not have root privilage access so I am not able to do sudo command. Is there a solution I can download the ROS packages and install it to directories that I can access?

note: I notice that the similar question has been asked, but the solution does not work for me.

Best,
Kang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9821/ros-offline-installation/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-04-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-26**:
Please clarify, are you looking for offline installation or non privledged installation(aka non root)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, if this is the easiest way, but you can just download the packages and extract their contents like so:`dpkg -x pkg.deb somedir` and then copy the ros files to a local ros directory.
Once you have setup the base ros files the extra packages shouldn't be that difficult as you only need to add their content to the stacks directory.

There will be no dependency tracking and it might even be easier (workwise) to just install ros from source without the debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is going to be tricky, almost no matter what. You're likely to need at least sporadic root access, because ROS splits its dependencies between ROS packages (OpenCV, for example, is stored in ROS) and OS-specific packaging systems (gtest, for example, is grabbed from somewhere else).

If you do a from-source install (see [the Ubuntu Source Install Instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source), for example), you'll spend awhile compiling, but this will build and install all of the ROS-packaged dependencies for you. For satisfying system-level dependencies, you'd need to pass along a few package-install requests to your sysadmin, or end up up to your elbows in building packages yourself. While doable, that would be a huge pain in the neck.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1